# How to add a device to my current provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile

I added the UDID of my iPad Air in Certificates, Identifiers, Profiles.  Under the DEVICES tab, in ALL, there is already a UDID for this device that I named also.

My provisioning profile has 1 device, my iPhone 6. How do I add my iPad Air into this provisioning profile so i'd have 2 total devices?

Status = Active (Managed by Xcode) in this provisioning profile

Answer (score 1):

Do this steps:

1. Go to Certificates part in Member Center (in [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com))
2. Add your iPad (as you added your iPhone 6 Plus) in Devices tab
3. Go to Provisioning Profiles tab and choose your Provisioning Profile
4. Click Edit and choose your iPad in the list of devices
5. Click Generate

Comment: I can't click EDIT in the Active (managed by xcode) one. I can only click EDIT in the one that's not managed by xcode.

Comment: Sorry for my previous ans, It only works for those provision profiles  managed manually form member center. Actually I researched and found that you cannot edit the provision profiles managed by Xcode. Sorry to say that but is at it is stated in Apple document. under **"Editing Provisioning Profiles in Member Center"** heading, **NOTE** section , you can clearly see stated

[https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW1]

Answer (score 1):

Log In developer portel,
Add your new device
Then Edit the provision and add the new device and Generate again(Better to rename the provision name).
Install the provision again.

Answer (score 0):

You can find stepwise procedure for maintaining your developer certificate ,provisioning profile and devices :

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html

For adding device into existing provisioning profile you have to edit profile and regenerate that again .